# Plymouth keeps quitting

Tags: opensuse, bootsplash

I'm setting up a customised single-purpose Linux image. It's based on OpenSUSE, and it uses Plymouth to display some nice graphics during startup and shutdown. The trouble is, for reasons beyond my comprehension, the Plymouth display keeps turning off. I need to prevent this from happening.

In particular, if I shutdown or reboot while X11 is running, Plymouth displays for 6ms and then I get a black terminal screen that says `Starting LSB: X Window Display Manager [ OK ]`. But if I press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to switch to one of the vterms and *then* issue a shutdown or reboot command, Plymouth displays perfectly.

Similarly, when the OS is first installed, I've set a script to run which reconfigure the OS, and then reboots it. The script also writes various messages to the Plymouth screen to indicate that something is actually happening. Trouble is, about half way through this process, Plymouth just quits, revealing a terminal full of random text. And then when the system reboots, Plymouth comes back. But I don't want it to ever close!

Does anybody know how I can fix these issues? Where to look for further troubleshooting? Anywhere that has any documentation for how Plymouth works?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the propriety nVidia video drivers seems to have fixed the problem. I would *still* like to know how to debug this properly, though...

Comment: Debugging issues regarding closed-source drivers is a tough one; and developers can't/won't help when it comes to these issues. Is there a special reason you need the proprietary driver instead of nouveau? Can you tell us more about the purpose of this image? Would this be an ISO, .img, ...?

Comment: Well, that's why we removed the nVidia drivers - apparently we _don't_ need them after all. I'd still like to know a bit more about how Plymouth works and so forth; there doesn't seem to be much documentation around.